# HTML .style visibility: hidden doesn't work

Tags: html, styles, visibility, hidden

My `div.style="visibility:hidden;` doesn't work. It is still visible even though I set it to be hidden.

My website: http://iogames.ga

In the bottom right corner,the inner layer "Chat" button is for hiding chat, while the button in the outer layer for opening chat.
By default, the outer layer should be hidden.

```
div id="chatdiv2" style="background-color:#003333; padding:5;
height:18; font-size:16px; color:#CCCCCC; visibility:hidden";
```

But I have no idea why the outer layer still appears by default.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: What's the mechanism for toggling the visibility on and off? Ideally, you should putting all styling in a separate stylesheet. Inline styling is fickle / hard to maintain.

Comment: @R. Amone Yeah, I tried, it's still not working.

Comment: @ghost_dad Supposingly, when I click inner layer, it will set chatdiv2's visibility to visible, while clicking outer layer will set chatdiv2's visibility to hidden.                                                                                                   And by default, its visibility is hidden so outlayer should be "hidden". But in reality, it's not.

Comment: Are you able to make a basic version of your site in a jsfiddle so we have something to play around with?

Answer (score 2):

Use display:none; instead of setting visibility. Also, currently it is showing visibility:visible on chatdiv2 for that matters.

Comment: What do you mean showing visibility: visible on chatdiv2? Because I put style="background-color:#003333; padding:5; height:18; font-size:16px; color:#CCCCCC; visibility:hidden"

Comment: It is showing visibility: visible; in inspector. Anyways, why don't you use display:none instead?

Comment: Try adding display:none !important; just in case if something else is overpowering it.

Comment: I tried adding this, and I even uploaded it to website and F12 it. It shows display:none   but still div2 appears in the website...

Comment: can you post the screenshot of inspector because on my side website is not showing any display:none style for div.

Answer (score 0):

`div id="chatdiv2" style="background-color:#003333; padding:5;
height:18; font-size:16px; color:#CCCCCC; visibility:hidden";`

If this is the entire code, it is bad syntax. There should be a `<` in front of the div and after it as this example shows:
`<div ...>`
And there should be a closing `<div>` tag:
`<div ...></div>`
And the semicolon `;` should be inside of the style quotes: 
`<div ... style="...";></div> <!--The wrong method-->`
`<div ... style="...;"></div> <!--The right method-->`

If you need more help, I will gladly help you.